# bootstrap fileinput css problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-file-upload

Using this plugin (http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) for some basic file upload but it's causing me a headache design wise. Don't know what's wrong. Seem to have all required js and css files.

```html
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/accordion.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/button.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/draggable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/menu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/resizable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/selectable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/selectmenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/sortable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/spinner.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/cldr/unresolved.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/message.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/plural.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/currency.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/relative-time.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/unit.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootbox.js"></script>

    <script src="/Content/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css"></script>
<script src="/Content/bootstrap-fileinput/themes/gly/theme.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/plugins/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/plugins/purify.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/plugins/sortable.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Neither do we, because you have not even explained what your problem is - what your expect, and what is actually happening!

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your reply. This is what it should look like: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input-ajax-demo/11  . I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong because I didn't do anything special in the Bootstrap css. Also I seem to have that Choose file button, which should not be there.

Comment: Seems this css file: /Content/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css was not taken into account. Moved this up a bit and now it seems to be working.